# Character encoding changes after window.open()

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, hyperlink

The site from where I'm calling the `window.open()` function is in UTF-8, using the `<meta>` tag, everything works well, but once I call the function and open another window with the same tag, the new window shows weird characters even thought in page info it shows that the encoding stays the same (UTF-8).

This is the same problem as mine:
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/622922-character-encoding-after-window-open

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Just use `unescape(decodeURIComponent( YOUR_URL ))` inside `window.open()`.

For example: `window.open(unescape(decodeURIComponent( YOUR_URL )), '_blank');`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.

Problem turned out to be that I was setting "Session.CodePage = 65001" in the window opened. That screwed up the character encoding for that session. So when I refreshed the "main" page, some characters (such as åäö) were suddenly garbled.

Solution: make sure the page in the new window doesn't change the session's code page. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Add a charset="UTF-8" attribute to your javascript tags. This will at least work if the cause of the garbled characters is your included javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser uses the same encoding for both pages (which, apparently, it does) then the problem must be in the page itself. It probably contains invalid UTF-8 to begin with.

Comment: Nope, it's written in the same editor (that work just fine). And also, if I don't open it in a new window, it works fine.

Comment: Weird... Can you reproduce it in another browser?

Comment: Yup, it's the same in FF 3.5 and in ie8. I also added a link to my question about someone with the same problem.