# How do I set the character encoding of a child window

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, window.open

I'm opening a child window and writing contents into it in JavaScript. The parent page has UTF-8 an the character set, but the child window opens with ISO-8859-1

I've tried using document.write to set the child page content type using the meta tag, but it appears to have no effect.

```
launcherHtml = '
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  </html>
'

sandbox = window.open()
sandbox.document.open()
sandbox.document.write(launcherHtml)
sandbox.document.close()

sandbox.document.characterSet // ISO-8859-1 !!!
```

I've also tried using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` as the tag in the child window but the results are the same.

How do I properly specify the charset of a popup window as UTF-8?

Comment: This appears to the the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140310/character-encoding-changes-after-window-open?rq=1 however that question has no accepted answer.  Perhaps one of the answers there works.

Comment: @EricJ. It does appear to be similar, but I think that question is asking about the parent page's encoding changing after opening a child window whereas I want to know how to set the encoding of a child window.

Comment: This doesn't completely solve your problem, but if you add a charset="UTF-8" tag to any javascript that is included in this child page, the javascript at least seems to work correctly. I was having an issue where UTF-8 characters in my includedjavascript were being misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

A method from late 2016 that works for multiple mime types including **"text/plain"** and **"text/html"**:

- use a data URL,
- specify mime-type
- specify character encoding as UTF-8.
- convert text to escaped UTF-8 characters using `uriEncode`
- replace '#' in the UTF octet string with "%23".

**JavaScript example** :

```
var launcherHtml = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>UTF-8 example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Example using unicode and '#'</h1>

    Hello folks, 你好! (nǐ hǎo) in Chinese, good evening,
    こんばんは (in Japanese).
    </body>
  </html>
`;

var launcherURL = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"
     + encodeURI( launcherHtml).replace(/#/g,"%23");

sandbox = window.open(launcherURL)

sandbox.document.characterSet // UTF-8, yippee
```